# How xaml Code sharing with Silverlight and WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

In Silverlight and WPF from code side we separate like this

```
#if SILVERLIGHT

#else

#endif
```

like How can we Share XAML is there any way

Answer (score 0):

The basic to separate your code is pretty simple:

- use a silverlight project
- use a .net project and add all your shared files with "add as a link" option

Then you could compile your code both for WPF and Silverlight. The code is write once, but you compile two DLL.

Use MVVM and and avoid as often as possible this if SILVERLIGHT/ELSE separation. If you have to use it too often, this is probably juste better to have 2 clear separate module with just a few part of the code shared (and this part should not required this if SILVERLIGHT/ELSE separation).

To be clear: no you can not do this kind of seperation in XAML. But you should not even beed it.